# Можно ли упростить мой код?

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки, list, инспекция-кода

Написал функцию-фильтр для текста. Если в тексте находится какое-то слово из запрещённого спам-списка - возвращаем False. Но есть еще 3 параметр функции если space_around == True слова считаются только если они стоят отдельно (перед словом пробел или это начало строки и после слова пробел или точка).
Но мне не нравится мой код визуально, как можно упростить его или это нормальная реализация?

```py
def is_spam_words(text, spam_words, space_around=False):
    text_l = text.lower()
    for word in spam_words:
        if text_l.find(word) != -1:
            if not space_around:
                return True
            elif space_around:
                if text_l[text_l.find(word) - 1] == ' ' or text_l.startswith(word)\
                        and text_l[text_l.find(word) + len(word)] == ' ':
                    return True
                else:
                    return False
        else:
            return False


text = 'Молох бог ужасен.'
spam_words = ['лох']
print(is_spam_words(text, spam_words, True))
```

Comment: Можно его упростить да пары строчек регулярными выражениями, но подойдёт ли такой вариант?

Comment: Да, я сейчас как раз начинаю изучать регулярные выражения

Comment: Пока в комментарии напишу тогда, в принципе должно быть достаточно `\b` то есть word boundary, [пример](https://regex101.com/r/ti2vMH/1), обрати внимание на флаг **case insensetive**. Далее при [компиляции](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.compile) регулярки можно подставлять слова из списка и искать по очереди через цикл, либо же собрать все слова в регулярку через `|`, т.е. `\bлох|мох|питух\b` и смотреть что быстрее отработает. Для небольшого массива запретных слов и большого текста вероятно второй вариант лучше. Оформлю в ответ, но сейчас засыпаю, возможно кто-то опередит.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Решение с [regex](/questions/tagged/regex):

```python
import re
def is_spam_words(text, spam_words, space_around=False):
    pattern = r'\b{}\b' if space_around else '{}'
    prog = re.compile(pattern.format('|'.join(spam_words)), re.I)
    return bool(prog.search(text))
```

Если стоит `space_around`, то регулярное выражение будет иметь `\b` по краям, что отвечает за word boundary и вполне выполняет условие:

> слова считаются только если они стоят отдельно (перед словом пробел или это начало строки и после слова пробел или точка).

Word boundary означает, что будет найдено слово не в составе какого-либо другого слова, а отдельно. Вокруг могут быть пробелы, точки. Тут правда стоит оговориться, что слова написанные через дефис будут считаться отдельными словами, то есть при поиске `\bнибудь\b` в строке `какой-нибудь` **нибудь** найдётся как отдельное слово.

Все слова в `spam_words` объединяются через `|`, то есть логическое **или**.

---

### Дополнение по комментарию:

Разберём строку `re.compile(pattern.format('|'.join(spam_words)), re.I)`
Ранее мы записали в `pattern` либо `{}` либо `\b{}\b` в зависимости от условия `space_around`. У строковых переменных есть метод [`.format()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format), который подставляет передаваемые в нём значения вместо `{}`.
В данном случае подставит значение из `'|'.join(spam_words)`, то есть все элементы массива `spam_words` разделённые знаком `|`:

```python
spam_words = ['лох']
print('|'.join(spam_words)) # лох

spam_words = ['лох', 'питух']
print('|'.join(spam_words)) # лох|питух
```

Эти значения подствляются вместо `{}`, соответственно получаем регулярные выражения для обоих случаев:

- **space_around** = True

  - `re.compile('\\bлох\\b', re.IGNORECASE)`
  - `re.compile('\\bлох|питух\\b', re.IGNORECASE)`
- **space_around** = False

  - `re.compile('лох', re.IGNORECASE)`
  - `re.compile('лох|питух', re.IGNORECASE)`

#### [`re.compile()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.compile)

Обычно излишний метод, можно обойтись строковой переменной и передать её напрямую в [`re.search()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search) первым аргументом, но компиляция, всё же, полезна.
Во-первых, при компиляции я указываю [флаг](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.I) `re.I`, который ранее упоминал в комментарии к вопросу, с ним будет искать вне зависимости от того заглавные буквы в тексте или строчные.
Во-вторых, скомпилированный паттерн можно переиспользовать как объект для поиска в другом [`pattern.search()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Pattern.search) методе, где как аргумент передавать только текст. В моём случае паттерн именуется `prog`, также как и в документации к регулярным выражениям.

Но можно обойтись и без компиляции, тогда код будет выглядеть так:

```python
import re
def is_spam_words(text, spam_words, space_around=False):
    pattern = r'\b{}\b' if space_around else '{}'
    return bool(re.search(pattern.format('|'.join(spam_words)), text, re.I))
```

## Update

Cпасибо Станиславу за интересный [комментарий](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1482431/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%83%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4/1482512?noredirect=1#comment2729688_1482512) и наблюдение.
Действительно **Лохундра** отработает неправильно. Причём, если выбрать другие языки ЯП на [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/1DpNc0/1), выдаёт ожидаемый результат, т.е. **False**.

Будет интересно изучить и разобраться в этой особенности [re](/questions/tagged/re) в [python](/questions/tagged/python), а пока решением для правильной работы видится упаковка всех слов в `\b`, а не только выражения в целом.

```python
def is_spam_words(text, spam_words, space_around=False):
    pattern = r'\b{}\b' if space_around else '{}'
    if space_around:
        prog = re.compile(pattern.format(r'\b|\b'.join(spam_words)), re.I)
    else:
        prog = re.compile(pattern.format('|'.join(spam_words)), re.I)
    return bool(prog.search(text))

print(is_spam_words('Лохундра', ['лох', 'питух'], True)) #False
```

Comment: А можете объяснить пожалуйста что делает строка "prog = re.compile(pattern.format('|'.join(spam_words)), re.I)"
И как паттерн понимает что нужно искать в spam_words если там стоит просто '{}'

Comment: @Pain дополнил ответ

Comment: `is_spam_words('лохудра', ['лох', 'питух'], space_around=True)` -> `True`. Должно быть `False`.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy интересное наблюдение, спасибо. Вы знаете, почему [изначальное выражение](https://regex101.com/r/1DpNc0/1) работает ожидаемо на всех языках кроме Python?

Comment: В случае с `'Лохундра'` можно просто добавить круглые скобки `pattern = r'\b({})\b' if space_around else '({})'`

Comment: @Be3y4uu_K0T круглые скобки [не помогают](https://regex101.com/r/gRz4Ia/1), либо я вас не до конца правильно понял.

Comment: Выражение должно быть `\b<слово>\b|\b<слово>\b|\b<слово>\b` или `\b(<слово>|<слово>|<слово>)\b`. Кроме того слова надо экранировать. Если кто-то введёт в качестве слова `в***е` результат будет неожиданным.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy к первому варианту пришёл, да. Работает как предполагается на Python, С# и Rust. Но в PHP, ECMA и GoLang перестаёт работать, на них работает второй вариант, изначальный в ответе. Интересно. Про экранировку, согласен, да, необходимо делать, но, предположим, что никто хулиганить не будет.

Answer (score 2):

Использовал следующий алгоритм:

1. При `space_around == False` при помощи `list comprehenshions` мы поочередно проверяем каждое слово из черного списка на включение в текст и возвращаем `True`, если итоговый список содержит хотя бы один элемент.
2. При `space_around == True`, когда нам необходимо проверить включение только целых слов в тексте, мы предварительно разбиваем текст на отдельные слова и уже проверяем их наличие в списке спам-слов.

Получилось довольно компактно:

```
def is_spam_words(text, spam_words, space_around=False):
    if space_around:
        return any([word for word in text.split() if word.lower() in spam_words])
    return any([word for word in spam_words if word in text.lower()])

text = 'Молох бог ужасен.'
spam_words = ['лох']
print(is_spam_words(text, spam_words, True)) # False
print(is_spam_words(text, spam_words, False)) # True
```

По-прежнему рекомендую вам изучить [list comprehenshions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), это
сделает ваш текущий код гораздо более понятным.

Comment: Сюда бы ещё downcase добавить, а то если запретное слово будет в начале предложения с заглавной буквы, то не отработает. List comprehensions сам обожаю, но далеко не всегда они добавляют коду читаемости.

Comment: @DiMithras  согласен, спасибо! Ну в данном случае это отличное решение, чтобы вложенные условия сократить

Comment: я когда комментарий писал, имел ввиду добавить в **list comprehension**, то есть `if word.lower() in spam_words`, возможно на большом тексте это будет эффективнее, но я не уверен.

Comment: @DiMithras как мне кажется - это будет эффективнее в случае, если `space_around == True`, то есть мы проверяем именно слова из **текста** на совпадение со списком, но у нас есть и другой вариант, когда уже нужно проверять слова из **списка** на совпадение с текстом, и тогда текст должен быть в нижнем регистре, иначе начало предложений будет пропускать, поэтому я решил, что оптимальнее всего - изначально обработать текст, раз это в любом случае будет необходимо

Comment: Понял, согласен да. Во втором случаем можно тогда сделать `if word in text.lower()`, и **если** downcase на всём тексте менее эффективен, пусть он будет для одного случая. Ни в коем случае не критика, просто размышления, мне решение с LC очень нравится.

Comment: @DiMithras соглашусь, так действительно будет более оптимально, сейчас добавлю в ответ!

Answer (score 1):

```python
def is_spam_words(text, spam_words, space_around=False):
    text_l = text.lower()
    for word in spam_words:
        if word not in text_l:
            return False
        if not space_around:
            return True
        
        index = text_l.find(word)
        return any((
            text_l[index - 1] == ' ',
            text_l[index+ len(word)] == ' ',
            text_l.startswith(word),
        ))


text = 'Молох бог ужасен.'
spam_words = ['лох']
print(is_spam_words(text, spam_words, True))
```

можно сделать так. Но ваш код (и то во что я его переделал) имеет несколько проблем:

- Если `space_around` равен `False`, то результат всегда будет `True`
- он не будет отрабатывать несколько слов, только первое